# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDemo.accounts'

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django app that will host a simple index.html file:

**url.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from PyDemo.accounts.views import my_view 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^demo/',my_view)
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.

def my_view(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\tcssuoy\Desktop\DJANGO\mysite\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\tcssuoy\workspace\PyDemo\PyDemo\PyDemo\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from PyDemo.accounts.views import my_view 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDemo.accounts'
```

Comment: If **PyDemo** is your project name and **accounts** is your app, then import as `from accounts.views import my_view`

Comment: What's the point of a Django app that just serves an HTML file? Why not make it a static page?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's for learning purpose.

Comment: @RanjithSinghu I tried that way too, but then the compiler doesn't recognize my_view. And deems it as Unresolved import. If I still execute then it shows 'Page Not Found'.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your project name is `PyDemo` and the name of the module is `accounts`. So try using

```py
from accounts.views import my_view
```

You may find an error (underlined by red mark) that is because of your IDE so ignore it and migrate it. It will work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue who is migrating from Python 2 to 3 it seems to be because Python 3 is more discerning about where to find modules. @Ranjith Singhu's comment sent me in the right direction. In my case I had to change:

Python 2:

```
from views import MyView
```

Python 3 (also fine in 2):

```
from project_name.views import MyView
```